# changing a value in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array

```
N America | S America | Europe | Asia | (blank)
```

I am trying to make a query of it. But I want to change some values. I have a code like this:

```
if (!empty($md)) {
    $mds = '';
    if(count($md) > 0 ){
       $mds .= 'AND ( FALSE';

       foreach($md as $key => $value){
         if ($key == '(blank)') {
            $value ='';
            $mds .= " OR data.m = '$value'";
         } else {

          $mds .= " OR data.m = '$value'";
         }
       }
       $mds .= ') ';
    }
}
```

And actually it finds the `'(blank)'` value and change it to `''`. But it at the end all I get is:

```
AND (FALSE
        OR data.m = ''
        OR data.m = 'S America'
        OR data.m = 'Europe'
        OR data.m = 'Asia'
        OR data.m = '(blank)')
```

It seems like it change the first value to my `''` and unfortunately there is still `'(blank)'` at the end.

My question is how to change a value in an array in a correct way?

Comment: Either `count` would cause an error as `$md` is not an array or it'd always be true as `empty` already checked it. It's unnecessary. The only reason for checking both is if you've extended `ArrayIterator`.

Comment: can you please print_r your array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if $value is '(blank)' not the key, so:

```
if ($value == '(blank)') { ... }
```

For a simple array like `$x = array('First','Second');` When you look over the array in a foreach, `$key` will be the index, so $x[0] would be the value 'First'.

Answer (score 0):

Change 7 line to:

```
if ($value == '(blank)') {
```

My scripts works with first value:

```
$md = Array('N America','S America','Europe','Asia','(blank)');

if (!empty($md)) {

    $mds = '';
    if(count($md) > 0 ){
       $mds .= 'AND ( FALSE';

       foreach($md as $key => $value){
         if ($value == '(blank)') {
            $value ='';
            $mds .= " OR data.m = '$value'";
         } else {

          $mds .= " OR data.m = '$value'";
         }
       }
       $mds .= ') ';
    }
}
```

AND ( FALSE OR data.m = 'N America' OR data.m = 'S America' OR data.m = 'Europe' OR data.m = 'Asia' OR data.m = '')